# How to prevent OSX Mail PDF export to split sentences (horizontally) at the end of the page?

Tags: macos, mail.app, pdf

When I export an email to a .pdf file in Mac OSX 10.9.5 it often splits sentences horizontally:

[image]

This also happens with images. Is there a way to prevent this (e.g. to push the last sentence to the next page)?

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue with Mail.app 8.2 in OSX 10.10.4.

The only solution I have found so far is to save the email as a rich text document, then open the text document in TextEdit and save as PDF.